# Building a list of random multiplication examples

Tags: python-3.x, list, random, multiplication

I have two 100-element lists filled with random numbers between 1 and 10.

I want to make a list of multiplications of randomly selected numbers that proceeds until a product greater than 50 is generated.

How can I obtain such a list where each element is a product and its two factors?

Here is the code I tried. I think it has a lot of problems.

```
import random
list1 = []
for i in range(0,1000):
    x = random.randint(1,10)
    list1.append(x)

list2 = []
for i in range(0,1000):
    y = random.randint(1,10)
    list2.append(y)

m=random.sample(list1,1)
n=random.sample(list2,1)

list3=[]
while list3[-1][-1]<50:
    c=[m*n]
    list3.append(m)
    list3.append(n)
    list3.append(c)
print(list3)
```

The output I want

> [[5.12154, 4.94359, 25.3188], [1.96322, 3.46708, 6.80663], [9.40574,
>   2.28941, 21.5336], [4.61705, 9.40964, 43.4448], [9.84915, 3.0071, 29.6174], [8.44413, 9.50134, 80.2305]]

To be more descriptive:

> [[randomfactor, randomfactor, product],......,[[randomfactor,
>   randomfactor, greater than 50]]

Comment: you are drafting integers. your demo has floats . whats its gonna be?

Comment: First of all, when you start iterating over list3, you will get IndexError, because you want to get last item of list from list, which has no elements. Is that clear? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepping two lists with 1000 numbers each with numbers from 1 to 10 in them is wasted memory. If that is just a simplification and you want to draw from lists you got otherwise, simply replace

```
a,b = random.choices(range(1,11),k=2)
```

by

```
a,b = random.choice(list1), random.choice(list2)
```

---

```
import random

result = []
while True:
    a,b = random.choices(range(1,11),k=2)  # replace this one as described above
    c = a*b
    result.append( [a,b,c] )
    if c > 50:
        break

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[9, 3, 27], [3, 5, 15], [8, 5, 40], [5, 9, 45], [9, 3, 27], [8, 5, 40], [8, 8, 64]]
```

---

If you need 1000 random ints between 1 and 10, do:

```
random_nums = random.choices(range(1,11),k=1000)
```

this if much faster then looping and appending single integers 1000 times.

---

Doku:

- [random.choices(iterable, k=num_to_draw)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)
- [random.choice(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)

Comment: Thank you, that is what I want.