# Randomly distribute numbers to lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, random

I have 4 empty lists. 
I would like to randomly distribute numbers starting from 1, until the sum of all the numbers in the lists exceeds 1000.

Here is the code I tried:

```
toplam=0
x=0
while toplam<1000:
    x+=1
    toplam+=x
a=[]
b=[]
c=[]
d=[]
list=[a,b,c,d]
z=[1,2,3,4]
import random
for i in range(x):
    t=random.choice(z)
    t2=list[t]
    t2.append(x)
print(list)
```

I want:

> [[2, 6, 8, 18, 20, 21, 28, 40, 43], [1, 5, 19, 23, 24, 25, 29, 31, 33,
>   34, 35, 37, 39, 45], [9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 22, 26, 36, 38, 44], [3,
>   4, 7, 12, 14, 16, 17, 27, 30, 32, 41, 42]]

Sum of lists:

> [186, 380, 224, 245]

Comment: 1. `z` doesn't contain the indices of the lists in `list`, indices are zero-based. 2. Why not just make a `random.choice` from `list` directly? 3. Don't use the name `list` in your own code, it shadows the built in type. 4. A [mcve] should include the actual output.

Comment: If I look back at your 4 questions (of which 1 was answered by me) it seems to me you are on some kind of "learn python track" course by supplying your task with some slightly related code riddled with holes to SO. If this is not the case I am sorry - if you do - stop it. This is the third question you get told to _not_ use `list` as variable name, its the second "random something" question today - you could have used what was provided to solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161460/building-a-list-of-random-multiplication-examples and applied it to this problem - you did not.

Comment: @PatrickArtner 
I think I'm misunderstood. You're right in a way, but I'm new to python, and I'm trying to improve myself. I saw the answer you wrote and tried to apply. Unfortunately I can't learn very fast. Thank you for your support and warnings. Yours sincerely,

Answer (score 2):

The indices in python start at 0.

```
import random

vals = [[] for _ in range(4)]
x = 0

while (x * (x + 1)) / 2 < 1000:
    t = random.randint(0,3)
    vals[t].append(x)
    x+=1

print(vals)
```